# Facebook customer chat `visually stuck` when coming directly from Facebook APP

Tags: facebook-chat, facebook-customer-chat

I got a website that uses facebook customer chat, it works very good from any browser.
but we posted the website link on facebook and after user sees & click the link on the facebook mobile app, the website is open on the "**facebook mobile browser"**, the "facebook customer chat icon" is visible on the right bottom corner, but after click on the icon i got two results

1. in android devices, got the "Continue as your_name_here", but if user click on the "continue" button NOTHING HAPPENS
2. in IOS devices, got "SESSION EXPIRED" message.

Any idea, will highly appreciate it.